# AngularJS - How to remove index from URL

Tags: angularjs

This works fine for now with a url like **test.com/#/album/0/the-slug-here**, but I'm trying to achieve **test.com/#/album/the-slug-here**

```
<a ng-href="#/album/{{$index}}/{{project.slug}}">{{project.title}}</a>

(function() {
var app = angular.module('chp', ['ngRoute', 'projectControllers']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/directory.html',
        controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
      }).
      when('/album/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/album.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl'
      }).
      when('/album/:id/:slug', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/album.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);

var projectControllers = angular.module('projectControllers', []);

projectControllers.controller('ProjectsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.projects = albums;
    $scope.filters = { };
  }]);

projectControllers.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$sce',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $sce) {
    $scope.project = albums[$routeParams.id];
}]);
```

When I remove the id though and try to just link to the slug, it's not loading in the data. The only way I've gotten to work so far is by adding the 2nd route which includes both. Any way to get rid of the index in the url?

Comment: Did you mean you are not able to do `/album/:slug` ? It just works fine to me http://plnkr.co/edit/9iYnxUmyVL0DupVZWpLC?p=preview

Comment: yeah doesnt work for me. i should say i have my data set up like so:

var albums = [
  {
   title: 'The Title',
   slug: 'the-slug,
   
  }, etc..
]

Comment: you are actually setting the 'slug' as the index

Comment: I want to be able to pass the index here $scope.project = albums[$routeParams.id]; without actually having to put the index into the URL. So I just would like to figure out a way to get the index of the particular album whose slug property equals the slug value

Comment: Ok so as i understand you will pass slug through route param and then need to match the index in albums which has slug property with that slug value from route, right?

Comment: yes,thats exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to remove both the routes with `:id` and replace with the one with `:\slug` and you can just filter the album from albums to get the index;

You can do:

In the router:

```
  when('/album/:slug', {
    templateUrl: 'album.html',
    controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl'
  }).
```

In the controller

```
  function($scope, $routeParams, $sce) {
    albums.some(function(album, idx){
       /*Search for a match*/
       if(album.slug === $routeParams.slug){
         /*Match found, set album and its index and break out*/
         $scope.album = album;
         $scope.albumIdx = idx;
         return true;
       }
    });
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrVNYmslrWlNLePrVLSf?p=preview)**

[Shim support for `Array.some` for older browsers here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: @user2994560  You are welcome. Please be aware of using array.some since it is not supported in older browsers, read the link attached you can either use a shim in the link or use traditional for loop with a break.